# CUDA C - cannot compile class that is declared in header file and implemented in .cu

Tags: c++, c, class, cuda, header-files

When I try to compile a simple `.cu` with its `.h` it gives me an error of:

```
name folloewd by "::" must be a class or namespace name
```

I use the following command in cmd

```
nvcc -c CuVec3.cu
```

**NOTE:** I have been able to compile things in this manner in the past, but never before with a class declared in `.h` then implemented in the `.cu`.

Here is the `CuVec3.h`:

```
#define __CUVEC3_H__
#ifndef __CUVEC3_H__

class CuVec3{
public:
    float x, y, z;
public:
    __host__ __device__ CuVec3(void);
    __host__ __device__ CuVec3(float, float, float);
    __host__ __device__ CuVec3 add(CuVec3*);
    __host__ __device__ CuVec3 subtract(CuVec3*);
    __host__ __device__ CuVec3 multiply(float);
    __host__ __device__ CuVec3 divide(float);
    __host__ __device__ float dot(CuVec3*);
    __host__ __device__ CuVec3 cross(CuVec3*);
    __host__ __device__ float magnitude(void);
    __host__ __device__ CuVec3 normalize(void);
public:
    __host__ __device__ inline CuVec3 operator+(const CuVec3);
    __host__ __device__ inline CuVec3 operator-(const CuVec3);
    __host__ __device__ inline CuVec3 operator*(const CuVec3);
    __host__ __device__ inline CuVec3 operator/(const CuVec3);

    __host__ __device__ inline CuVec3 operator+=(const CuVec3);
    __host__ __device__ inline CuVec3 operator-=(const CuVec3);
    __host__ __device__ inline CuVec3 operator*=(const CuVec3);
    __host__ __device__ inline CuVec3 operator/=(const CuVec3);
};

#endif
```

Here is `CuVec3.cu`:

```
#include "CuVec3.h"

__host__ __device__ CuVec3::CuVec3(void){ // Error thrown on this line <-----
    x = 0.0f; y = 0.0f; z = 0.0f;
}
__host__ __device__ CuVec3::CuVec3(float x, float y, float z){
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
}
__host__ __device__ CuVec3 CuVec3::add(CuVec3 *v){
    x += v->x;
    y += v->y;
    z += v->z;
    return *this;
}
// ... Other things implemented
```

Comment: You have a broken preprocessor definition sequence in your header file. `CuVec3` is never getting imported into the translation unit.

Comment: If I may clarify what @talonmies said, you have the first two lines of `CuVec3.h` switched around. Thus, the code inside the `#ifndef` is never seen by the compiler.

Comment: @AviGinsburg  Want to provide an answer? I would upvote.  It's obviously a critical issue.

Comment: @talonmies I cannot express how stupid I feel right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Robert Crovella, I'm changing my comment to an answer.

In `CuVec3.h` the first two lines are (a mixed up version of) what is known as an "#include guard". In order to avoid a single file being included multiple times due to multiple `#includes`. More details can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

If we look at the preprocessor sees as it looks at the first two lines, we can understand what happened. The first line defines `__CUVEC3_H__`, basically a flag. The second line (`#ifndef`) checks to see if the macro name (`__CUVEC3_H__`) is defined, and if it is *not*, then uses the code until `#else` or `#endif`. Using `#ifdef` would do the opposite (it wouldn't help here, though). So, the preprocessor sees that `__CUVEC3_H__` is already defined and skips the enclosed code. Effectively, the `#include "CuVec3.h"` in the `.cu` file added the following line.

```
#define __CUVEC3_H__
```

Switch the first two lines in the `.h` file and it should compile.

Comment: I really hate that this is the answer.